# Solving $a_k=a_{k-1}^2 -2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How do I solve this recurrence relation for a given $a_0$? I only know how to do linear ones by substituting $a_k=\lambda^k$ and solving for $\lambda$ but this doesn't work here

Comment: Hint: $\cos(2\theta) = 2\cos^2\theta - 1$ and $\cosh(2\theta) = 2\cosh^2\theta - 1$

Comment: Solving recurrence $a_k = a_{k-1}^2 + c$ is possible (in some precise sense) only when $c=0$ or $c=-2$.  Achille provided the hint for the case $c=-2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $|a_0|\le 2$, by induction $a_n=2\cos (2^n\arccos\frac{a_0}{2})$. If $|a_0|> 2$, by induction $a_n=2\cosh (2^n\operatorname{arcosh}\frac{a_0}{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

This [paper](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/11-4/aho-a.pdf) contains the very general answer for your question. Because your $g_n$ (following the notation therein) is always negative, the closed form is simply $[k^{2^n}]$ for some $k$ and large enough $n \geq n_0$. Also, $k$ will depend on $a_0$, and if $a_0$ is (positive) integer, determining $k$ becomes quite easy.